# C# List<Interface>: why you cannot do `List<IFoo> foo = new List<Bar>();`

Tags: c#, generics

If you have an Interface `IFoo` and a class `Bar : IFoo`, why can you do the following:

```
List<IFoo> foo = new List<IFoo>();  
foo.Add(new Bar());
```

But you cannot do:

```
List<IFoo> foo = new List<Bar>();
```

Comment: Btw, how does that work in the first example? If Bar1 and Bar2 both implement IFoo, you would be able to add a new Bar1() and a new Bar2() to the same list?

Answer (score 147, accepted):

At a casual glance, it appears that this *should* (as in beer *should* be free) work. However, a quick sanity check shows us why it can't. Bear in mind that the following code **will not compile**. It's intended to show why it isn't allowed to, even though it *looks* alright up until a point.

```
public interface IFoo { }
public class Bar : IFoo { }
public class Zed : IFoo { }

//.....

List<IFoo> myList = new List<Bar>(); // makes sense so far

myList.Add(new Bar()); // OK, since Bar implements IFoo
myList.Add(new Zed()); // aaah! Now we see why.

//.....
```

`myList` is a `List<IFoo>`, meaning it can take any instance of `IFoo`. However, this conflicts with the fact that it was instantiated as `List<Bar>`. Since having a `List<IFoo>` means that I could add a new instance of `Zed`, we can't allow that since the underlying list is actually `List<Bar>`, which can't accommodate a `Zed`.

Comment: sorry the example is throwing the same error `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<WebApplication1.Models.Bar>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<WebApplication1.Models.IFoo>`
`  for this line `List<IFoo> myList = new List<Bar>();`

Comment: @AhammadaliPK (and anyone else reading this comment): it's **supposed** to fail. This is mentioned in the answer text already. The point of the example is to illustrate why that line of code is illogical and thus isn't allowed by the compiler. It's not intended to show how to do it, it's intended to show why it can't be done!

Answer (score 52):

The reason is that C# does not support co- and contravariance for generics in C# 3.0 or earlier releases. This is being implemented in C# 4.0, so you'll be able to do the following:

```
IEnumerable<IFoo> foo = new List<Bar>();
```

Note that in C# 4.0, you can cast to IEnumerable<IFoo>, but you won't be be able cast to List<IFoo>. The reason is due to type safety, if you were able to cast a List<Bar> to List<IFoo> you would be able to add other IFoo implementors to the list, breaking type safety.

For more background on covariance and contravariance in C#, Eric Lippert has a [nice blog series](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/tags/Covariance+and+Contravariance/default.aspx).

Answer (score 16):

If you need to convert a list to a list of a base class or interface you can do this:

```
using System.Linq;

---

List<Bar> bar = new List<Bar>();
bar.add(new Bar());

List<IFoo> foo = bar.OfType<IFoo>().ToList<IFoo>();
```

Comment: I believe the .OfType<IFoo>() part is redundant.  I was able to get away without it.

Answer (score 4):

It is to do with the creation of the List, you have specified the T to be IFoo therefore you cannot instantiate it as a Bar since they are different types, even though Bar supports IFoo.

Answer (score 3):

I used some linq to make the conversion easier

```
List<Bar> bar = new List<Bar>();
bar.add(new Bar());

List<IFoo> foo = bar.Select(x => (IFoo)x).ToList();
```

It is a little less versbose than other answers but works well

Answer (score 2):

If you have a list of type `List<IFoo>` you can call `list.add(new Baz());`  assuming `Baz` implements `IFoo`. However you can't do that with a `List<Bar>`, so you can't use a `List<Bar>` everywhere you can use a `List<IFoo>`.

However since `Bar` implements `IFoo`, you can use a Bar everywhere you use `IFoo`, so passing a Bar to add works when it expects and `IFoo`.

Answer (score 2):

Because a list of `IFoo`s can contain some `Bar`s as well, but a list of `IFoo`s *is not* the same thing as a list of `Bar`s.

Note that I used English above instead of using C#. I want to highlight that this is not a deep problem; you are just getting confused by the details of the syntax. To understand the answer you need to see beyond the syntax and think about what it actually means.

A list of `IFoo`s can contain a `Bar`, because a `Bar` is an `IFoo` as well. Here we're talking about the elements of the list. The list is still a list of `IFoo`s. We haven't changed that.

Now, the list you called `foo` is still a list of `IFoo`s (more pedantically, `foo` is declared as a `List<IFoo>`). It cannot be anything else. In particular, it cannot be made into a list of `Bar`s (`List<Bar>`). A list of `Bar` is a completely different object than a list of `IFoo`s.

Answer (score 1):

List is the type in this case and it's not an inheritance question List<IFoo> really is different than List<Bar>.  List doesn't know anythign of, or inherit the characteristics of either IFoo or Bar.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

`List<Bar>` does not inherit from `List<IFoo>`