# IList<> Property stays null even when member is instantiated

Tags: c#, properties, null, ilist

I am having trouble using an IList property which always seems to return null, even though the member is is getting is instantiated:

```
    private List<ModelRootEntity> _validTargets = new List<ModelRootEntity>();

    public IList<IModelRootEntity> ValidTargets
    {
        get
        {
            return _validTargets as IList<IModelRootEntity>;
        }
        protected internal set
        {
            if (value == null)
                _validTargets.Clear();
            else
                _validTargets = value as List<ModelRootEntity>;
        }
    }
```

`ModelRootEntity` implements `IModelRootEntity`. I watched both values during debugging, whilst the member shows a positive count, the property stays null.

I also tried raising an exception within the property getter to throw if the counts of `_validTargets` and `_validTargets as List<ModelRootEntity>` are different, but it never threw.

Found question [Dictionary properties are always null despite dictionaries being instantiated, which seems similar, however in my case this seems to happen regardless of serialization.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you casting at all? Why not make the types match?

Comment: Why dont you change it to `private List<IModelRootEntity> _validTargets = new List<IModelRootEntity>(new List<ModelRootEntity>());`

Comment: SLaks, Nilesh, good question. Probably deserves its own thread. I am open to advice on this. The `ModelRootEntity` is used within the domain and many internal methods expect more members than `IModelRootEntity` declares (which are the ones exposed via DTO's outside the domain). So I either cast once inside the property or in every internal use. Figured, doing it once was cleaner.

Comment: @SLaks, Nilesh, decided to open this as a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18560845/exposing-a-listdomain-objects-via-an-ilistinterface

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, thanks to @Nilesh comment above.

Replacing:

```
private List<ModelRootEntity> _validTargets = new List<ModelRootEntity>();
```

with:

```
private List<IModelRootEntity> _validTargets = new List<ModelRootEntity>();
```

exposed the real issue. The second line will not compile. The following post explained why:
[C# newbie List<Interface> question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228173/c-sharp-newbie-listinterface-question)

The only odd thing was the exception I tried to force which never threw, and "threw" me off.

Answer (score 0):

If you set your property to any value that isn't a `List<ModelRootEntity>`, the `as` expression will return `null` and the property will become null.