# Lists of Generics Implementing an interface

Tags: c#, generics

I've been reading [C# newbie List<Interface> question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228173/c-sharp-newbie-listinterface-question) and can understand why this first example works, but not the second. Why is the first good, but the second piece of code fails to compile.

First the good code:

```
interface IFoo {}
class Foo : IFoo { }
class Bar : IFoo { }

        var list = new List<IFoo>();
        list.Add(new Foo());
        list.Add(new Bar());
```

Now for the code which introduces generics

```
interface IZar<TFoo> where TFoo : IFoo { }
class ZarFoo : IZar<Foo> { }
class ZarBar : IZar<Bar> { }

        var list2 = new List<IZar<IFoo>>();
        list2.Add(new ZarFoo());
        list2.Add(new ZarBar());
```

This is failing to compile because ZarFoo cannot be converted to IZar when surely it should be able to as it implements IZar where Foo : IFoo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `IZar<TFoo>` is not [co-variant](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183.aspx). You can't downcast the interface just like that.

You have to make `IZar<TFoo>` co-variant, by using `out`:

```
interface IZar<out TFoo> where TFoo : IFoo { }
```

The problem becomes clear when you create an add method:

```
interface IZar<TFoo> where TFoo : IFoo
{
    void Add(TFoo foo);
}
class ZarFoo : IZar<Foo>
{
    public void Add(Foo foo)
    { }
}
class ZarBar : IZar<Bar>
{
    public void Add(Bar foo)
    { }
}
```

If you would use the interface, you could end up adding an `IFoo`, where the actual type is an `Foo` or `Bar`. Returning doesn't have that problem since `IFoo` can be either `Foo` or `Bar`. See, there is no inheritance problem:

```
interface IZar<out TFoo> where TFoo : IFoo
{
    TFoo GetOne();
}
class ZarFoo : IZar<Foo>
{
    public Foo GetOne()
    { return new Foo(); }
}
class ZarBar : IZar<Bar>
{
    public Bar GetOne()
    { return new Bar(); }
}
```

Comment: Great examples and illustrate the problems very well, thanks for taking the time to explain. The MSDN link is very verbose across several pages! For the short version - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997386.aspx