# How to inherit a List<> of base objects as List<> of derived objects?

Tags: c#, list, inheritance

Is it possible to inherit a List of base objects as List of derived objects? Don't know how to explain it better. Hope this example makes it clear:

```
public abstract class MyBase
{ }

public class MyConcrete: MyBase
{ }

public abstract class MyBases: IList<MyBase>
{
    internal abstract List<MyBase> Items { get; set; }
    public MyBase this[int index] { get => ((IList<MyBase>)Items)[index]; set => ((IList<MyBase>)Items)[index] = value; }

    // other implementations of IList...
}

public class MyConcretes: MyBases
{
    //Possible:
    internal override List<MyBase> Items { get; set; }

    // Needed
    internal override List<MyConcrete> Items { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The variance rules of C# will not let you do this with `List<T>` because `T` appears as both an input and an output.  You may be able to get something to work if you use `IReadOnlyList<T>` instead, which (I believe) is covariant on `T`.

Comment: @MikeStrobel So the only possibility I have is to use the "MyBase" and cast it every time?

Comment: you can make your class generic to handle this. as a side note you should not inherit from IList, its rare that you actually need to extend the functionality of a list, you probably just want to keep a list as an internal member

Comment: If someone finds a better wording for the title, then please change.

Comment: @MikeStrobel: That's correct; it is covariant.

Comment: @MikeStrobel this may be a stupid question: The answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/55404316/1574221) works. Will I run in any problems using it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# List<Interface>: why you cannot do \`List<IFoo> foo = new List<Bar>();\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228173/c-sharp-listinterface-why-you-cannot-do-listifoo-foo-new-listbar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use template class.

```
public abstract class MyBases<T> : IList<T>
{
    internal abstract List<T> Items { get; set; }
    public MyBase this[int index] { get => ((IList<MyBase>)Items)[index]; set => ((IList<MyBase>)Items)[index] = value; }

    // other implementations of IList...
}

public class MyConcretes : MyBases<MyConcrete>
{
    internal override List<MyConcrete> Items { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this does what you want.  Casting a `List<T>` to an `IList<MyBase>` will generate a runtime error if T is not `MyBase`.

Comment: T should derive from MyBase, not IList<T>.