# Method doesn't work with interface as parameter

Tags: c#, .net

I want `HasOverlappingTimeSpans` to only require the presence of two properties, `FromDate` and `ToDate`. However, when I changed the parameter from `List<JobTitle>` to `List<IDateRange>` it gives me an error saying it can't convert between the data types.

The following is a complete example to replicate the error:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var jobTitles = new List<JobTitle>();
        var hasOverlaps = HasOverlappingTimeSpans(jobTitles);
    }

    public static bool HasOverlappingTimeSpans(List<IDateRange> dateRanges) // <-- Cause of error
    {
        return false; // Dummy
    }
}

public interface IDateRange
{
    DateTime FromDate { get; set; }
    DateTime? ToDate { get; set; }
}

public class JobTitle : IDateRange
{
    public DateTime FromDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ToDate { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

Error I'm getting:

> Argument 1: cannot convert from
> 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to
> 'System.Collections.Generic.List'

I have done a clean, rebuild, Visual Studio restart and the error persists. .NET fiddle also gives the same error, so it shouldn't be an issue from elsewhere in my project.

Comment: pls check this article https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228173/c-sharp-listinterface-why-you-cannot-do-listifoo-foo-new-listbar

Comment: Basically your method should accept an `IEnumerable<IDateRange>` or `ICollection<IDateRange>`, which are generically covariant.

Comment: Short: while a `JobTitle` "is-a" `IDateRange`, `List<JobTitle>` and `List<IDateRange>` are two completely unrelated types.